# Использование MySQL-функций: INTERVAL, DAY

Tags: jpa, formula, hibernate, java, mysql

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@Formula(value = "(SELECT count(history.city_id) FROM history where history.ts > (now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) and history.city_id = id)")
private int last30daysUpdates;
```

Так вот, хибернейт преобразует эту строку в:

```
 ...where
            history.ts > (
                now() - entitycity0_.INTERVAL 30 entitycity0_.DAY
            ) ...
```

И ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '30 entitycity0_.DAY)

Как дать понять хиберу, что INTERVAL и DAY - это функции mysql? Возможно? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

You could override org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect and add required keyword e.g. in the constructor

```
registerKeyword("day");
registerKeyword("interval");
```

May also want to add other interval types.
Don't forget to register your dialect in the `hibernate.dialect` property.
BTW, DAY and INTERVAL are not the fucntions, they are keywords - an important difference for `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect`

Comment: надо проверить)

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что Hibernate тут ни причем. Сам запрос написан неверно. По идее должно быть так:

```
(SELECT count(history.city_id) FROM history where history.ts > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and history.city_id = id)
```

Comment: Даже если как у вас написать, всё равно ошибка, он к INTERVAL и к DAY приписывает суффикс.

Comment: Да, странно.
Но может попробуете что наподобие как [тут][1]?


  [1]: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?71639-sql-to-Hql